# How to autoincrement the index and print the array values in render?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an array of names and I need to loop through the index and print the names in render

```
    const names = ['John','Sara','Michael','Timothy']`
render: (props) => ({
<div>
props=names[];
</div>
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const names = ["John", "Sara", "Michael", "Timothy"];
class Content extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Names</h1>
        {this.props.names ? (
          this.props.names.map((name, index) => (
            <p key={name + index}>{name}</p>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>No names found</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Content names={names} />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You yan use **for ... in** loop to iterate through indexes.

```js
const names = ['John','Sara','Michael','Timothy'];
for(const index in names) {
  console.log(`${index} of ${names[index]}`); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` to accomplish your demand.

```
   render() {
     const names = ['John','Sara','Michael','Timothy'];
   
     return (
        <div>
            { names.map((name, index) => <div key={index}>{ name }</div> }
        </div>
     );
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to improve the part of your code. It doesn't seem like a JSX part. Here, how I suppose it can be:

```
render() {
    const names = ['John','Sara','Michael','Timothy'];
    return <div>
            {names.map((item, index) => (
               <div key={index}>
                  {item}
               </div>
            ))}
          </div>;
}
```